# Check if all comboboxes are not empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form where I need to put several information to schedule a medical appointment.

Before I register the appointment, I want the code to check if any of the textboxes and comboboxes are empty, and If so, to display a `MsgBox` telling that it'is empty and restart the filling of the form (without losing all the other comboboxes/textboxes that aren't empty).

My code:

```
Private Sub btCadastra_Click()
    Sheets("AGENDA").Select

    lastrow1 = (Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Range("A" & lastrow1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Dim data_cad As Date

    id = lastrow1

    ActiveCell = id
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = cmbProfissional
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    ActiveCell = txtData
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = txthorario
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = cmbDescricao
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = cmbNomePaciente
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = cmbStatus
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Time

    MsgBox "Dados cadastrados com sucesso", vbExclamation

    Unload Me
    frmAgenda.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of form? You need to provide more details. You also need to include the code you've tried to use and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: This should be implementable by a simple if-clause

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
Private Sub btCadastra_Click()
    Dim c As Control, lastRow As Long, data_cad As Date, rng As Range

    'This loop checks for empty fields, exits sub if found (i.e. return to userform)
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
            If c.Value = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    'I've tried to tidy your code to write the fields to your s/sheet

    With Worksheets("AGENDA")
       lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       Set rng = .Range("A" & lastrow).Offset(1, 0)

       rng.Offset(0, 1) = cmbProfissional
       rng.Offset(0, 4) = txtData
       rng.Offset(0, 5) = cmbDescricao
       rng.Offset(0, 6) = cmbNomePaciente
       rng.Offset(0, 7) = cmbStatus
       rng.Offset(0, 8) = cmbStatus
       rng.Offset(0, 9) = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Time
    End With

    MsgBox "Dados cadastrados com sucesso", vbExclamation
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If cmbNomePaciente.ListRows >0 And cmbDescricao.ListRows >0 And cmbNomePaciente.ListRows >0  then
    msgbox "No Box is Empty"
Else
    msgbox "One of the Box is Empty"

Endif
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer; code-only answers often don't fare well with readers who may not be skilled enough to implicitly understand what your code is doing.